# Windows 8 C# Xaml doesn't continue program flow after running Azure query

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, azure-mobile-services

Im developing a Windows 8.1 app with Azure Mobile service table support. My program gets stuck (when I say stuck I mean the next line of execution doesn't get executed) after I run a query agaisnt Azure Mobile service:

```
var testQuery = await _testTable.Take(1).ToCollectionAsync();
```

I checked Fiddler and I do get the result back from Azure as expected. I also checked the `_testTable` entity and it does have correct structure and components. 
Visual Studio doesn't throw any errors. It just doesn't continue the execution.
Any tips are appreciated. :)

Comment: How is this code called? Do you have a `Wait` or `Result` further up your call stack?